# Look up more than one item in a data extension with ampscript in email

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript, dataextensions

I understand the basics of looking up one entry from a data extension, but I have a data extension of products and I would like to display the image, name, url for three, can I do that with one LookupRows?

```
%%[

var @ProductNumber, @ProductName, @ProductImageURL, @ProductPageURL, @rows, @rowCount, @i, @row, @ProductNumber2, @ProductNumber3

/* Need to set this to the product number of the item in cart */
set @ProductNumber = "003835"
set @ProductNumber2 = "003837"
set @ProductNumber3 = "003839"

/* Get the product info based on the product number */
set @rows = LookupRows("Products_DE","Product_Number__c", @ProductNumber)
set @row = Row(@rows, 1)

/*Set the email variables to the product info*/
set @ProductName = field(@row,"Name")
set @ProductPageURL = field(@row,"PDP_Page__c")
set @ProductImageURL = field(@row,"Product_Image_URL__c")
]%%
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few option when conducting product multiple lookups, and the option you choose may depend on how you want to display the results:

You can hard-code the 3 individual lookups explicitly and store each value for later use in the email:

```
%%[
/* Lookups */
set @product1 = Row(LookupRows("Products_DE","Product_Number__c","003835"),1)
set @Product1Name = field(@product1,"Name")
set @Product1PageURL = field(@product1,"PDP_Page__c")
set @Product1ImageURL = field(@product1,"Product_Image_URL__c")

set @product2 = Row(LookupRows("Products_DE","Product_Number__c","003837"),1)
set @Product2Name = field(@product2,"Name")
set @Product2PageURL = field(@product2,"PDP_Page__c")
set @Product2ImageURL = field(@product2,"Product_Image_URL__c")

set @product3 = Row(LookupRows("Products_DE","Product_Number__c","003839"),1)
set @Product3Name = field(@product3,"Name")
set @Product3PageURL = field(@product3,"PDP_Page__c")
set @Product3ImageURL = field(@product3,"Product_Image_URL__c")
]%%
```

Or you can run a FOR LOOP that conducts a search for each product listed and outputs the required HTML for each result found:

```
%%[
SET @products = BuildRowsetFromString('003835|003837|003839', '|')
for @i = 1 to Rowcount(@products) do
set @product = Row(LookupRows("Products_DE","Product_Number__c",Row(@products, @i)),1)
set @ProductName = field(@product,"Name")
set @ProductPageURL = field(@product,"PDP_Page__c")
set @ProductImageURL = field(@product,"Product_Image_URL__c")
]%%
Product #%%=v(@i)=%%<br>
<a href="%%=v(@ProductPageURL)=%%" title="%%=v(@ProductName)=%%">
Name: %%=v(@ProductName)=%%<br>
<img src="%%=v(@ProductImageURL)=%%"/><br>
</a><br>
%%[next @i]%%
```

**Reference:**
 - [BuildRowSetFromString](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/buildrowsetfromstring.htm)

You can read more on for loops in the [AMPScript Elements Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/languageElements.htm#using-the-for-process-loop), in the [BuildRowSetFromString documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/buildrowsetfromstring.htm), in the [AMPScript 401](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/AMPscript401.htm) guide, and at https://ampscript.guide/process-loops/